# jQuery Table rows hide show - working separately on each table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build a script that limits table rows to 10 and add link to display more - but I need to do it with more than one table.

I've got something like that http://jsfiddle.net/ot6fe3no/ but when I click rows are added in all tables.

Here is the code:

```
 (function( $ ){
       $.fn.tablaraize = function() {

    var numShown = 5; // Initial rows shown & index
    var numMore = 5;  // Increment

    var $table2 = $(this);  // tbody containing all the rows

    var $table = $(this).find('tbody');  // tbody containing all the rows
    var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows


    // Hide rows and add clickable div
    $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
        .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
               $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show more</div</tbody></td></tr>');

    $table2.find('#more').click(function() {
        numShown = numShown + numMore;
        // no more "show more" if done
        if (numShown >= numRows) {
            $table2.find('#more').remove();
        }
        $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show();
    });  

   }; })( jQuery );


    $('table').tablaraize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your fiddle

```
 (function( $ ){
       $.fn.tablaraize = function() {

    var numShown = 5; // Initial rows shown & index
    var numMore = 5;  // Increment

    var $table2 = $(this);  // tbody containing all the rows

    var $table = $(this).find('tbody');  // tbody containing all the rows
    var numRows = $table.find('tr').length; // Total # rows


    // Hide rows and add clickable div
    $table.find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end()
        .after('<tbody id="more"><tr><td colspan="' +
               $table.find('tr:first td').length + '"><div>Show more</div</tbody></td></tr>');

    $table2.find('#more').click(function() {
        numShown = numShown + numMore;
        // no more "show more" if done
        if (numShown >= numRows) {
            $table2.find('#more').remove();
        }
       // $table.find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show(); this will run on all table 
$(this).parent("table").find('tr:lt(' + numShown + ')').show(); // show the rows of current clicked 
    });  

   }; })( jQuery );


    $('table').tablaraize();
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ot6fe3no/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, it's working but I found two problems:
1. Show more is not disapearing when all rows are visible, I fix it with:

```
        // no more "show more" if done
        if (numShown+1 >= numRows) {
            //$table2.find('#more').remove();
            $(this).parent("table").find('#more').remove();
        }
```

2. When there is 2 rows - Show more is appearing, I cant find the way the way around this